# Why is the core resistance modeled as 2*Rp and capacitance as Cp/2 in a common-mode choke?

Tags: high-frequency, common-mode, vna, common-mode-choke, crosstalk

I directed my attention to a paper regarding the modeling of common-mode chokes. Within this paper, the authors structured the circuit in such a manner that they designated the core resistance (parallel to the inductor) as 2*Rp, and the capacitance to be equal to Cp/2. What is the rationale behind this approach? Furthermore, what alterations would occur to the same circuit if I were to design a multiple resonance circuit for a common-mode choke?
[image]

Here's [https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8094720](https://www.example.com/) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ry996.png): [Characterization of Common-Mode Choke for Automotive Ethernet Networks enabling
100 Mbit/s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ry996.png)

Comment: What's the rational? Why not?!

Comment: According to Fig 6 it matches reality pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, the resistances RP represent magnetic material losses and Cp the parasitic self-capacitances of the windings.

If you need to design a multiple-resonance circuit, you should have a more complete model. There are also leakage inductances and capacitances between choke inputs and outputs.

Comment: Thanks you for your valuable feedback ...